# Heroku deployment with text files

Tags: heroku, deployment

I am new to web application world. I have made an app and ready to deploy on Heroku. I have tested and it is working. 
Problem is that I have static 62 text files (each 1KB, so total 62 KB size) which I feed data (numbers) from the files and display on web page.

I am using java for back-end / js, JQuery, CSS, ajax, etc for front-end. 
Application is working fine and I have tested for the deployment on Heroku.

Originally, I used external sever for the data and fetch the data from the server and display it on my web application.

However, the sever connection wants to keep the confidentiality, so I was recommended to use static files.

The files only include numbers. ex) 356, 200, 100, 280,....etc 
So here are my questions.

**1) How can I upload 62 text files (each 1KB) on Heroku?**

(I don't know about django, Ruby on rails.. what so ever???? All answers are about those. but I do NOT think I am USING those. but I don't know, I am very newbie.)

**2) when my app on Heroku try to use data from the text files on Heroku (after I figure out how to upload), How my connection URL can be in java code to fetch the data from those text files (I mean usually there are url address I am giving )**

Current to code to fetch data from the server.. I am doing like this

```
String addressURL = "http://url_address_bla:xxxx/data/bla";

URL url = new URL(addressURL);
//then I open the file and read the file..etc
```

Thanks in advance.